# In Pandas documentation, how to tell class vs instance? Seems ambiguous - basic, ubiquitous and confusing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, naming-conventions

I'm pretty new to Pandas and would like to read the consistent thorough documentation, but I'm confused by the [seeming?] ambiguity in all of the headings, and I couldn't find an intro describing the documentation conventions.  Compare:

Example 1:
(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#)
**pandas.DataFrame**
class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=None)

Example 2:
(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html)
**pandas.DataFrame.size**

property DataFrame.size

So, to make a dataframe and get its size, I start with Example 1:
import pandas as pd
df = **pd.DataFrame( my_data)**

Next, I'll extract the size using Example 2:
size_of_my_data = **pd.DataFrame.size**
#wth?

I'm finally catching on that DataFrame could mean either the class or an instance of the class.  It's not differentiated by "DataFrame" vs. "my_dataframe"
So my question is, how to know instantly which it is?
In this case, how would I instantly know that I needed to interpret 'pandas.DataFrame' verbatim the first time, and as 'df' the second time, and write:
size_of_my_data = df.size

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. `pandas.DataFrame.size` is a `property` as it says in the documentation, and `pandas.DataFrame` is a `class` also noted in the documentation. Are you trying to resolve a general rule as to which aspects of the pandas libraries are properties, methods, or class definitions? In which case, this is not possible as this is largely a design decision and the docs will need to be referenced for usage until you are familiar with the options available. Or are you generally unclear on the definitions of these terms and looking to better understand the current docs?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.size` is a property of the DataFrame class and therefore exposed on instances.  You usually invoke it on your dataframe instance, like `df.size`.  If this is still unclear, consider writing your own simple classes and playing with its properties/methods for greater clarity

Comment: Here's a clearer version of my question:  A newbie might ask, "what does 'pandas.DataFrame' mean in the documentation?"  Since the answer is NOT consistently 'a class included in pandas', since sometimes it is 'an instance of a DataFrame that you created', what would you tell a newbie?

Comment: I think a better way to understand this is to understand from the oo perspective what a class and an instance is.  If you understand from the oo perspective, then class and instance in pandas would be easier to understand.  The class is provided by pandas.  It's a model for you to create your own working dataframe with data.  Say you have a csv file, how do you bring the data in the csv into the computer memory to work with it ?  The pandas class gives you the model to bring the data into memory and give you the methods, attributes, etc to manipulate your data.